# Long Short Term Memory (LSTM) model does not fit dataset

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Recurrent Neural Network model, particularly I am using LSTM to predict views count of a movie in the next time slot.

I take dataset from the link:  https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/latest/

After processing the dataset,  I try a small dataset including the number of views count of a movie ('movieId' =1) within 90 days from 2015-01-01 to 2015-03-31. My dataset has a size of 90 rows (daytime) and 1 column (views count), for example, below is the view count for the first 4 days:

Time              count
2015-01-01          6

2015-01-02          6

2015-01-03          4

2015-01-04          8

Next, I learn how to predict the next viewcount by using LSTm. I found the code in the link below and try with my dataset: 
(https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)

What I do is just modifing the code by loading my dataset "movie.csv" as in the following code (in the "Load data set " part):

```
######################## LOAD AND PREPROCESS DATASET
# Ratings dataset
ratings = read_csv('ratings.csv')
print('Shape of the ratings data frame:', ratings.shape)

# convert timestamp to date form
def convert_time(timestamp, lag):
    date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    int(timestamp)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if lag==1:
        return date
    else:
        return int(date[0:4])

ratings['time']=ratings['timestamp'].apply(convert_time, lag=1) # take full time form

# drop timestamp 
data = ratings.drop(['timestamp', 'userId', 'rating'],  axis=1) 

# subset of days from '2015-01-01' to  '2015-03-31'
data = data[(data.time >= '2015-01-01') & (data.time <= '2015-03-31')]

# sort by time 
data = data.sort_values(by='time')

# Swap 2 columns
columnTitles = ['time','movieId']
data = data.reindex(columns = columnTitles)

# reset index
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

# Find duplicate rows
duplicateRowsDF = data[data.duplicated(keep=False)]

# reset index
duplicateRowsDF = duplicateRowsDF.reset_index(drop=True)

# generate a table of those culprit rows which are duplicated
dups = duplicateRowsDF.groupby(data.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
one_movie_df = dups[dups['movieId']==1].drop('movieId',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# fill in missing date
data = one_movie_df
count = data['count']
time = pd.to_datetime(data['time']) # Convert the data frame index to a datetime index
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'count': count})
r = pd.date_range(start=df.time.min(), end=df.time.max())
df = df.set_index('time').reindex(r).fillna(0).astype(int).rename_axis('time')
one_movie_df = df # DAY VIEW COUNT DATA FOR MOVIE 1



######################### LSTM MODEL
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# load the dataset
dataframe = one_movie_df
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

# plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

However, the result is bad, because the prediction is not fit the test set and even the train set.

Below is my result image, in which the blue line represents the original dataset, the orange one represents the prediction for the training dataset and the green one represents the prediction for the testing dataset

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvghq.png

Anyone can help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It'd help if you (1) include your full relevant code; (2) share the size of your entire dataset along its dimensions (shapes).

Comment: will you be able to show how you preprocess the data? Time step etc...

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. From the Movielens dataset (27,000,000 ratings applied to 58,000 movies by 280,000 users). My purpose is to predict the popularity of movies. First, I tried with 1 movie in a specific period of time. Specifically, I extracted view count by day of a movie with MovieId =1 from 2015-01-01 to 2015-03-31. Then I had a data like above.